# Change bootstrap modal title created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap modal created on the fly like this

```
var popupTemplate = '
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="dropzoneModalTitle"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body dropBox" id="dropzoneModalBody"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
';
```

then with a `onClick` listener with jquery i create a modal with that template like this

```
$(button).click(function(){
   $(popupTemplate).modal()
});
```

i want to change the title of that modal created on the fly, but is not working with this

```
var modal = $(popupTemplate).modal();
modal.find('.modal-title').text('HELLO');
```

any help for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try modifying the HTML before creating the modal:

```
var modal = $(popupTemplate);
modal.find('.modal-title').text('HELLO');
modal.modal();
```

Comment: You could'nt be more right in this answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to change it inside the show event. Just add an id attr to the root div and do the following:

```
 $('#modalId').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        $('#dropzoneModalTitle').text('My New Modal Title');

  });
```